# MY didBeginContact() FUNCTION DOES NOT WORK SWIFT SPRITE KIT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Hi I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time, my problem is that my didBeginContact() does not work the "rocket" collides with the "missiles" and they get pushed down but it does not run the function, what can I do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

```
    //
//  PlaysScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket3
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 27/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import spriteKit

class PlayScene:SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
    //declaring the node in this scene!
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")



    let bara = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let barb = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let barc = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bard = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bare = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let barf = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let barg = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let barh = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bari = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let barj = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar7 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar8 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar9 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let missile1  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile2  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile3  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile4  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile5  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile6  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile7  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile8  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile9  = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile10 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile11 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile12 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile13 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile14 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
    let missile15 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Missile")
       let rocket = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"rocket")

    var  leftTouch = false
    var  rightTouch = false
    enum colideType:UInt32{
        case rocket = 1
        case missile = 2
    }

        var actionmove = SKAction.moveToY(-150, duration: 15)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        let print = SKAction.runBlock({
        println("moved")
        })
        let actionmove1 = SKAction.sequence([actionmove,print])

        var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.5))
        var delchild = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(10)
        self.rocket.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.rocket.size)

        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        rocket.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        rocket.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        rocket.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()

        missile1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile1.size)
        missile2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile2.size)
        missile3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile3.size)
        missile4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile4.size)
        missile5.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile5.size)
        missile6.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile6.size)
        missile7.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile7.size)
        missile8.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile8.size)
        missile9.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile9.size)
        missile10.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.missile10.size)

        missile1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile4.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile5.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile6.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile7.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile8.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile9.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        missile10.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

        missile1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile5.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile6.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile7.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile8.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile9.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()
        missile10.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colideType.missile.toRaw()

        missile1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile5.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile6.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile7.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile8.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile9.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        missile10.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false


        missile1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile5.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile6.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile7.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile8.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile9.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile10.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()

      missile1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile4.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile5.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile6.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile7.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile8.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile9.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()
        missile10.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = colideType.rocket.toRaw()


        missile1.yScale = 0.35
        missile2.yScale = 0.35
        missile3.yScale = 0.35
        missile4.yScale = 0.35
        missile5.yScale = 0.35
        missile6.yScale = 0.35
        missile7.yScale = 0.35
        missile8.yScale = 0.35
        missile9.yScale = 0.35
        missile10.yScale = 0.35

        missile1.xScale = 0.6
        missile2.xScale = 0.6
        missile3.xScale = 0.6
        missile4.xScale = 0.6
        missile5.xScale = 0.6
        missile6.xScale = 0.6
        missile7.xScale = 0.6
        missile8.xScale = 0.6
        missile9.xScale = 0.6
        missile10.xScale = 0.6

        let delayA = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
        let delayB = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(4.0))
        let delayC = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(6.0))
        let delayD = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(8.0))
        let delayE = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(10.0))
        let delayF = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(12.0))
        let delayG = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(14.0))
        let delayH = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(16.0))
        let delayI = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(18.0))
        let delayJ = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(20.0))

        var missile1Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
        self.missile1.hidden = true
        })

        var missile2Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile2.hidden = true
        })

        var missile3Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile3.hidden = true
        })

        var missile4Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile4.hidden = true
        })

        var missile5Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile5.hidden = true
        })

        var missile6Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile6.hidden = true
        })

        var missile7Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile7.hidden = true
        })

        var missile8Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile8.hidden = true
        })

        var missile9Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile9.hidden = true
        })

        var missile10Hide = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile10.hidden = true
        })

        var missile1show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile1.hidden = false
        })

        var missile2show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile2.hidden = false
        })

        var missile3show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile3.hidden = false
        })

        var missile4show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile4.hidden = false
        })

        var missile5show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile5.hidden = false
        })

        var missile6show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile6.hidden = false
        })

        var missile7show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile7.hidden = false
        })

        var missile8show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile8.hidden = false
        })

        var missile9show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile9.hidden = false
        })

        var missile10show = SKAction.runBlock({
            self.missile10.hidden = false
        })

        var position1 = SKAction.runBlock({
        println("1")
        self.missile1.position =  CGPointMake(600,850)
        })

        var position2 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("2")
            self.missile2.position = CGPointMake(300,850)

        })
        var position3 = SKAction.runBlock({

            self.missile3.position = CGPointMake(100,850)
          println("3")
        })
        var position4 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("4")
            self.missile4.position = CGPointMake(900,850)

        })
        var position5 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("5")
            self.missile5.position = CGPointMake(300,850)

        })
        var position6 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("6")
            self.missile6.position = CGPointMake(600,850)

        })
        var position7 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("7")
            self.missile7.position = CGPointMake(200,850)

        })
        var position8 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("8")
            self.missile8.position = CGPointMake(600,850)

        })
        var position9 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("9")
            self.missile9.position = CGPointMake(900,850)

        })
        var position10 = SKAction.runBlock({
            println("10")
            self.missile10.position = CGPointMake(200,850)

        })







        let sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([missile1Hide,delayA,position1,missile1show,actionmove])
        let sequence2 = SKAction.sequence([missile2Hide,delayB,position2,missile2show,actionmove])
        let sequence3 = SKAction.sequence([missile3Hide,delayC,position3,missile3show,actionmove])
        let sequence4 = SKAction.sequence([missile4Hide,delayD,position4,missile4show,actionmove])
        let sequence5 = SKAction.sequence([missile5Hide,delayE,position5,missile5show,actionmove])
        let sequence6 = SKAction.sequence([missile6Hide,delayF,position6,missile6show,actionmove])
        let sequence7 = SKAction.sequence([missile7Hide,delayG,position7,missile7show,actionmove])
        let sequence8 = SKAction.sequence([missile8Hide,delayH,position8,missile8show,actionmove])
        let sequence9 = SKAction.sequence([missile9Hide,delayI,position9,missile9show,actionmove])
        let sequence10 = SKAction.sequence([missile10Hide,delayJ,position10,missile10show,actionmove])

        let s1 = SKAction.sequence([delayA,position1,actionmove1])
        let s2 = SKAction.sequence([delayB,position2,actionmove1])
        let s3 = SKAction.sequence([delayC,position3,actionmove1])
        let s4 = SKAction.sequence([delayD,position4,actionmove1])
        let s5 = SKAction.sequence([delayE,position5,actionmove1])
        let s6 = SKAction.sequence([delayF,position6,actionmove1])
        let s7 = SKAction.sequence([delayG,position7,actionmove1])
        let s8 = SKAction.sequence([delayH,position8,actionmove1])
        let s9 = SKAction.sequence([delayI,position9,actionmove1])
        let s10 = SKAction.sequence([delayJ,position10,actionmove1])

        let r1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s1)
        let r2 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s2)
        let r3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s3)
        let r4 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s4)
        let r5 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s5)
        let r6 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s6)
        let r7 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s7)
        let r8 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s8)
        let r9 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s9)
        let r10 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(s10)




        //actionmove: making it smooth

        //doing stuff with the background
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        background.yScale = 10.0
        background.xScale = 10.0
        addChild(background)
        addChild(rocket)
        rocket.yScale = 0.3
        rocket.xScale = 0.6




        addChild(missile1)
        addChild(missile2)
        addChild(missile3)
        addChild(missile4)
        addChild(missile5)
        addChild(missile6)
        addChild(missile7)
        addChild(missile8)
        addChild(missile9)
        addChild(missile10)


        self.missile1.runAction(r1, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r1)
        })

        self.missile2.runAction(r2, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r2)
        })

        self.missile3.runAction(r3, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r3)
        })

        self.missile4.runAction(r4, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r4)
        })

        self.missile5.runAction(r5, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r5)
        })

        self.missile6.runAction(r6, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r6)         })

        self.missile7.runAction(r7, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r7)
        })


        self.missile8.runAction(r8, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r8)
        })


        self.missile9.runAction(r9, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r9)
        })


        self.missile10.runAction(r10, completion:{
            self.missile1.runAction(r10)
        })
        rocket.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 200)

        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
            if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene{
                let skView = self.view as SKView!
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }



        }
    }





    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
            var loc = location.x
            var tapLoc = SKAction.moveToX(loc, duration: 3.5)
           tapLoc.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
            rocket.runAction(tapLoc)


        }
    }






    }
```

Comment: You need to isolate and post the code snippet(s) what you believe to be causing your issue. Don't dump your entire implementation file. Not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: So much repeated code...You should "tweak" it a little. Make your own class Missile and initialize it with default data, instead of repeating same actions for each missile...I am just curious, why do you need so much variables (for each missile) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing in didMoveToView:

```
//not sure if it is needed but almost everyone sets the gravity to 0,0 unless needed
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

Also `didBeginContact` should be outside of didMoveToView and you have it inside.

Hopefully that helps.